# Question about French PAL DS games

Tags: nintendo-ds, pal

There is a ds game I am wanting to buy on ebay, but the seller is from france and the ds cart is PAL. If I put the game in my ntsc 3ds or ds lite, would there be an option to change the language to english?

Comment: That highly depends on the game. Normally, PAL games come with English, French, German, Italian and Spanish. But some larger games may not support all languages.

Comment: No way to answer this without knowing what game you're asking about.

Comment: The game is Yu-Gi-Oh! Nightmare troubadour.

Comment: @Victor I just now read that you intend to use the game in an NTSC 3DS. Do you mean by that, that it's a US 3DS? Because as far as I know the 3DS is region-locked and can't play games from different regions. I think the DS Lite should work though.

Answer (score 1):

As Nolonar mentioned in the comments, usually PAL DS games include English, French, German, Italian and Spanish. The languages are usually stated on the back of the box.

Keep in mind though, that the Nintendo DSi and 3DS are region locked, and games from the PAL region can only be played on systems from the same region. The original DS [is not region locked](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/162063/are-ds-games-region-locked).

In your specific case of "Yu-Gi-Oh! Nightmare Troubadour", all of the above languages are included:

[image]